How to specify multiple jvm arguments when building a docker image with jib?
I try to build my Quarkus app with jib using the following properties:
quarkus.jib.base-jvm-image=registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.19-1

quarkus.jib.jvm-arguments=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments="-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90"

I tried  with and without , and quotes for the quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments but it throws the following error when i try to run the container:
Error: Could not find or load main class  -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50

During the image build, the containers entrypoint is set correctly with both additional jvm args.
Container entrypoint set to [java, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, "-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90", -jar, quarkus-run.jar]

When i build the container manually with the src\main\docker\Dockerfile.jvm image
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.19-1

ENV LANGUAGE='en_US:en'


# We make four distinct layers so if there are application changes the library layers can be re-used
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/lib/ /deployments/lib/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/*.jar /deployments/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/app/ /deployments/app/
COPY --chown=185 target/quarkus-app/quarkus/ /deployments/quarkus/

EXPOSE 8080
USER root
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90"
ENV JAVA_OPTS_APPEND="-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
ENV JAVA_APP_JAR="/deployments/quarkus-run.jar"

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/container/java/run/run-java.sh" ]

the errors mentioned above do not occur and the container starts with the given jvm memory properties.

Change:
quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments=-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50, -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90
into
quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments="-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=50 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=90"
PS: you missed the quotes around the arguments. Also I think, I may be wrong, you should remove the ,.
